Related fields in tabular bibliographies
I am trying use a tabular output of biblatex for data that are related. In the bib file, there are entries of non-standard type education that are related. For two of the educations, the field place is shared, and I would then only output it once.
The related output seems to work better with \printbibliography, so it seems there is something different with \printbibtabular.
Below is an attempt together with a tabular in the bottom of the desired output.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[datamodel=cvdata, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\addbibresource{cvdata.bib}

\newbibmacro*{related:serialeducation}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
  }
}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}%
{%
 \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.90\textwidth}}
}
{
  \end{tabular}
}
{
    & \plainlang{\printfield{place}} \\
    & \plainlang{\printfield{title}} \\
    & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{related:serialeducation}} \\
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
  \printbibtabular[title={Tabular references}]

  \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.90\textwidth}}
    & Copenhagen \\
    & \textit{Doctor of Philosophy in Physics} \\
    & \\
    & Rome \\
    & \textit{Master of Science in Physics}\\
    & \textit{Bachelor of Science in Physics} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}

cvdata.bib:
@education{cph,
  title = {Doctor of Philosophy in Physics},
  place = {Copenhagen},
  date = {2016-09/2021-05},
}
@education{rome,
  place = {Rome},
  related = {rome:msc,rome:bsc},
  relatedtype = {serialeducation},
}
@education{rome:msc,
  crossref = {rome},
  title = {Master of Science in Physics},
  date = {2014-08/2016-06},
  options = {dataonly},
}
@education{rome:bsc,
  crossref = {rome},
  title = {Bachelor of Science in Physics},
  date = {2011-08/2014-06},
  options = {dataonly},
}

and the specification of the non-standard type education is given by:
\ProvidesFile{education.dbx}

\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{education}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{
  place,
  title,
  date
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[education]{
  place,
  title,
  date,
  related,
  relatedtype
}



The related fields are usually printed by calling the two bibmacros
\usebibmacro{related:init}%
\usebibmacro{related}

Those macros will then call the type-specific bibmacros with the appropriate arguments. Calling the related:<relatedtype> macros directly will not work unless you put in some extra work.
Note that related may not work together with a tabular bibliography perfectly well if you essentially expect related to produce an entry of its own. I'm also not sure if biblatex really is the best tool for the job of producing something that looks like the education section in a CV. Most likely the sorting etc. will always stay the same, so introducing biblatex and all its overhead to make use of only a fraction of its features may be overkill.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{education.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{education.dbx}

\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{education}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{
  place,
  title,
  date
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[education]{
  place,
  title,
  date,
  related,
  relatedtype
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[datamodel=education, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@education{cph,
  title = {Doctor of Philosophy in Physics},
  place = {Copenhagen},
  date = {2016-09/2021-05},
}
@education{rome,
  place = {Rome},
  related = {rome:msc,rome:bsc},
  relatedtype = {serialeducation},
}
@education{rome:msc,
  crossref = {rome},
  title = {Master of Science in Physics},
  date = {2014-08/2016-06},
  options = {dataonly},
}
@education{rome:bsc,
  crossref = {rome},
  title = {Bachelor of Science in Physics},
  date = {2011-08/2014-06},
  options = {dataonly},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{related:serialeducation}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
  }
}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}%
{%
 \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.90\textwidth}}
}
{
  \end{tabular}
}
{
    & \plainlang{\printfield{place}} \\
    & \plainlang{\printfield{title}} \\
    & \plainlang{%
        \iftoggle{bbx:related}
          {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
           \usebibmacro{related}}
          {}} \\
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
  \printbibtabular[title={Tabular references}]

  \begin{tabular}{p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.90\textwidth}}
    & Copenhagen \\
    & \textit{Doctor of Philosophy in Physics} \\
    & \\
    & Rome \\
    & \textit{Master of Science in Physics}\\
    & \textit{Bachelor of Science in Physics} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}


